# How do I calculate bpm (beats per minute)?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write a Winforms application that calculates the beats per minute of click, similar to this website: https://www.all8.com/tools/bpm.htm but nothing works for me.

I've tried to create a `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` object to count the number of milliseconds, and divide that by 60,000 to get the number of minutes that pass, but that doesn't count what the future

```
public Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
float i = 0f;
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!stopwatch.IsRunning) { stopwatch.Start(); }
    i++;
    speed.Text = String.Format("Speed: {0} bpm\nClicks: {1} Clicks", i / Millis(), i);
}        
private float Millis()
{
    var returntype = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 60000;
    return returntype + 1;
}
```

This just counts the number of times you've clicked the button and divides it by the number of minutes *that have passed*, and doesn't predict at the rate of clicking.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide more specifics, including a _precise_ description of what it is you want the code to do that it doesn't do now. Calculating the rate of clicks ("beats per minutes") is trivial and, poor method name and random `+1` in the code notwithstanding, what you have does that fine. What else do you want it to do? What does it mean to _"predict at the rate of clicking"_?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a couple of utility ex. methods that convert between BPM and `TimeSpan`:

```cs
public static class BpmExtensions
{
  const long SecondsPerMinute = TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond;

  public static int ToBpm(this TimeSpan timeSpan)
  {
    var seconds = 1 / timeSpan.TotalSeconds;
    return (int)Math.Round(seconds * SecondsPerMinute);
  }

  public static TimeSpan ToInterval(this int bpm)
  {
    var bps = (double)bpm / SecondsPerMinute;
    var interval = 1 / bps;
    return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(interval);  
  }          
}
```

Comment: very good answer

Answer (score -2):

This is very similar to some code I wrote to calculate FPS of an encoding process that I wrote some time ago.

Start with this code and then adapt it to your needs. The Calculate method will take a bool indicating whether it's a click or not. You'll call it with True on every click, and have a timer call it with False every second. Then you simply bind the BMP to the property of this class for display.

This should be enough to get you started. I recommend keeping the logic of that calculation in a specialized class to not clutter the main class.

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows calculating the time left during an encoding process.
/// </summary>
public class TimeLeftCalculator {

    private KeyValuePair<DateTime, long>[] progressHistory;
    private int iterator;
    private bool fullCycle;
    private long lastPos;
    private long frameCount;
    private int historyLength;
    /// <summary>
    /// After calling Calculate, returns the estimated processing time left.
    /// </summary>
    public TimeSpan ResultTimeLeft { get; private set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// After calling Calculate, returns the estimated processing rate per second.
    /// </summary>
    public double ResultFps { get; private set; }

    protected readonly IEnvironmentService environment;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the TimeLeftCalculator class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="frameCount">The total number of frames to encode.</param>
    /// <param name="historyLength">The number of status entries to store. The larger the number, the slower the time left will change. Default is 20.</param>
    public TimeLeftCalculator(long frameCount, int historyLength = 20) : this(new EnvironmentService(), frameCount, 20) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the TimeLeftCalculator class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="environmentService">A reference to an IEnvironmentService.</param>
    /// <param name="frameCount">The total number of frames to encode.</param>
    /// <param name="historyLength">The number of status entries to store. The larger the number, the slower the time left will change. Default is 20.</param>
    public TimeLeftCalculator(IEnvironmentService environmentService, long frameCount, int historyLength = 20) {
        this.environment = environmentService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(environmentService));
        this.FrameCount = frameCount;
        this.HistoryLength = historyLength;
        progressHistory = new KeyValuePair<DateTime, long>[historyLength];
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the total number of frames to encode.
    /// </summary>
    public long FrameCount {
        get => frameCount;
        set => frameCount = value >= 0 ? value : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(FrameCount));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the number of status entries to store. The larger the number, the slower the time left will change.
    /// </summary>
    public int HistoryLength {
        get => historyLength;
        set => historyLength = value >= 1 ? value : throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(HistoryLength));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculates the time left and fps. Result will be in ResultTimeLeft and ResultFps.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pos">The current frame position.</param>
    public void Calculate(long pos) {
        if (pos < 0)
            return;

        TimeSpan Result = TimeSpan.Zero;
        progressHistory[iterator] = new KeyValuePair<DateTime, long>(environment.Now, pos);
        lastPos = pos;

        // Calculate SampleWorkTime and SampleWorkFrame for each host
        TimeSpan SampleWorkTime = TimeSpan.Zero;
        long SampleWorkFrame = 0;
        int PosFirst = -1;
        if (fullCycle) {
            PosFirst = (iterator + 1) % HistoryLength;
        } else if (iterator > 0)
            PosFirst = 0;
        if (PosFirst > -1) {
            SampleWorkTime += progressHistory[iterator].Key - progressHistory[PosFirst].Key;
            SampleWorkFrame += progressHistory[iterator].Value - progressHistory[PosFirst].Value;
        }

        if (SampleWorkTime.TotalSeconds > 0 && SampleWorkFrame >= 0) {
            ResultFps = SampleWorkFrame / SampleWorkTime.TotalSeconds;
            long WorkLeft = FrameCount - pos;
            if (WorkLeft <= 0)
                ResultTimeLeft = TimeSpan.Zero;
            else if (ResultFps > 0)
                ResultTimeLeft = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(WorkLeft / ResultFps);
        }

        iterator = (iterator + 1) % HistoryLength;
        if (iterator == 0)
            fullCycle = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What namespace can I find IEnvironmentService?

Comment: That's my own class, it's following Dependency Injection patterns. People generate call that class IDateProvider. Either create a class and interface with a simple Now method, or just replace those lines with DateTime.Now to get started without bothering about advanced coding patterns. The advantage of having a separate class is that you can then unit test the classes, and provide specific times needed for the tests (controlling the context of the test). If you're just getting started, don't worry about that.